# Mule 4: SFTP connector loosing connections in CloudHub with pipe closed error

Tags: sftp, mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub

With reconection strategy FOREVER, it keeps attempting for reconnections even after success.

Configuration: [SFTP Connection configuration attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqCIN.jpg)

Error:

```
[2021-09-15 04:31:37.141] WARN  org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource [[MuleRuntime].uber.99: [p-biztalk-api-prod].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$10:376 @7d65bb9e]: Message source 'listener' on flow 'hkm-exp-jd-implementationFlow' successfully reconnected

[2021-09-15 05:33:44.987] ERROR  org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener [_pollingSource_hkm-exp-jd-implementationFlow/executor.01]: Found exception trying to poll directory '/Out/Products/JD/'. Will try again on the next poll. 

org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Found exception trying to obtain path /Out/Products/JD/

at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.command.AbstractFileCommand.exception(AbstractFileCommand.java:209)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:89)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getExistingFile(SftpCommand.java:70)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpListCommand.list(SftpListCommand.java:77)

at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileSystem.list(AbstractFileSystem.java:112)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener.poll(SftpDirectoryListener.java:184)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.lambda$poll$3(PollingSourceWrapper.java:192)

at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedRunnable.run(CheckedRunnable.java:22)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.withWatermarkLock(PollingSourceWrapper.java:497)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.poll(PollingSourceWrapper.java:189)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.lambda$onStart$0(PollingSourceWrapper.java:136)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.DelegateRunnable.run(DelegateRunnable.java:41)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)

at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableRepeatableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableRepeatableFutureDecorator.java:83)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Could not obtain attributes for path /Out/Products/JD/

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:412)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:408)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:141)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:87)

... 17 more

Caused by: org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException: Error occurred while trying to connect to host

... 20 more

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 

at org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException.<init>(SftpConnectionException.java:38)

... 20 more

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 

... 20 more

Caused by: 4: 

at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:2204)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:136)

... 18 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)

at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:362)

at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:2194)

... 19 more

 

 

[2021-09-15 05:33:44.988] WARN  org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource [_pollingSource_hkm-exp-jd-implementationFlow/executor.01]: Message source 'listener' on flow 'hkm-exp-jd-implementationFlow' threw exception. Attempting to reconnect...

org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException: Error occurred while trying to connect to host

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:408)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:141)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:87)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getExistingFile(SftpCommand.java:70)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpListCommand.list(SftpListCommand.java:77)

at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileSystem.list(AbstractFileSystem.java:112)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener.poll(SftpDirectoryListener.java:184)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.lambda$poll$3(PollingSourceWrapper.java:192)

at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedRunnable.run(CheckedRunnable.java:22)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.withWatermarkLock(PollingSourceWrapper.java:497)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.poll(PollingSourceWrapper.java:189)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.PollingSourceWrapper.lambda$onStart$0(PollingSourceWrapper.java:136)

at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.poll.DelegateRunnable.run(DelegateRunnable.java:41)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)

at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableRepeatableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableRepeatableFutureDecorator.java:83)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 

at org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException.<init>(SftpConnectionException.java:38)

... 20 more

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 

... 20 more

Caused by: 4: 

at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:2204)

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:136)

... 18 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)

at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:362)

at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:2194)

... 19 more
```

Comment: Not just for polling even writing files doesnt happen with API deployment status green and logs grow with reconnections even after successfull connection.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.
Also please add the version of Mule and the version of the SFTP connector used in your application.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably caused by networking issues that the SFTP connector is not able to recover from. There is nothing you can do about that.